# Multivariable regression interaction term with categorical variables

Tags: r, glm, interaction

I am kind of new to R and am working on glm model and wanted to look for the interaction effect of BMI groups and patient groups (4 groups) on mortality (binary) in subgroup analysis. I have the following codes:

```
model <- glm(death~patient.group*bmi.group, data = data, family = "binomial")
summary(model)
```

and I get the following:

```
Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               -3.4798903  0.0361911 -96.153  < 2e-16 ***
patient.group2             0.0067614  0.0507124   0.133    0.894    
patient.group3             0.0142658  0.0503444   0.283    0.777    
patient.group4             0.0212416  0.0497523   0.427    0.669    
bmi.group2                 0.1009282  0.0478828   2.108    0.035 *  
bmi.group3                 0.2397047  0.0552043   4.342 1.41e-05 ***
patient.group2:bmi.group2 -0.0488768  0.0676473  -0.723    0.470    
patient.group3:bmi.group2 -0.0461319  0.0672853  -0.686    0.493    
patient.group4:bmi.group2 -0.1014986  0.0672675  -1.509    0.131    
patient.group2:bmi.group3 -0.0806240  0.0791977  -1.018    0.309    
patient.group3:bmi.group3 -0.0008951  0.0785683  -0.011    0.991    
patient.group4:bmi.group3 -0.0546519  0.0795683  -0.687    0.492    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So as displayed I will have a p-value for each of the `patient.group:bmi.group`. My question is, is there a way I can get a single p-value for `patient.group:bmi.group` instead of one for each subgroup? I have tried to look for answers online but I still could not find the answer :(

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `glm(death ~ patient.group + bmi.group + as.numeric(patient.group):as.numeric(bmi.group), data=data, family="binomial")
`.

Comment: @jay.sf your approach makes assumptions that I feel should be spelt out in detail as they may not always be valid.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you regard your patient and BMI groups as *factors* or continuous *covariates*.  If they are covariates, @jay.sf's suggestion is appropriate.  It fits a single degree of freedom term for the interaction between the linear effect of patient group and the linear effect of BMI group.

But this depends on both the ordering and definition of the groups.  It assumes, for example, that the "difference" between patient groups 1 and 2 is the same as that between patient groups 2 and 3 and so on.  Is the ordering of patient groups such that, in some way, group 1 < group 2 < group 3 < group 4?  Similarly for BMI.  This model would also assume that a change of 1 unit on the patient scale was "the same" as a change of one unit on the BMI scale.  I don't know if these are reasonable assumptions.

It would be more usual to consider both patient group and BMI group as factors.  This assumes no ordering in groups, nor that the difference between any two groups was equal to that between any other two.  In this case, jay.sf's suggestion would give a misleading answer.

To illustrate my point...

First, generate some artifical data as you haven't provided any:

```
data <- tibble() %>% 
          expand(patient.group=1:4, bmi.group=1:3, rep=1:5) %>% 
          mutate(
            z=-0.25*patient.group + 0.75*bmi.group, 
            death=rbernoulli(nrow(.), exp(z)/exp(1+z))
          ) %>% 
          select(-z)
```

Fit a simple continuous covariate model with interaction, as per jay.sf's suggestion:

```
covariateModel <- glm(death~patient.group * bmi.group, data = data, family = "binomial")
summary(covariateModel)
```

Giving, in part

```
Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)              -2.6962     1.8207  -1.481    0.139
patient.group             0.7407     0.6472   1.144    0.252
bmi.group                 1.2697     0.8340   1.523    0.128
patient.group:bmi.group  -0.3807     0.2984  -1.276    0.202
```

Here, the p value for the `patient.group:bmi.group` interaction is a Wald test based on a single degree of freedom z test.

A slightly more complicated approach is necessary to fit the factor model with interaction and obtain a test for the "overall" interaction effect.

```
mainEffectModel <- glm(death~as.factor(patient.group) + as.factor(bmi.group), data = data, family = "binomial")
interactionModel <- glm(death~as.factor(patient.group) * as.factor(bmi.group), data = data, family = "binomial")
anova(mainEffectModel, interactionModel, test="Chisq")
```

Giving

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: death ~ as.factor(patient.group) + as.factor(bmi.group)
Model 2: death ~ as.factor(patient.group) * as.factor(bmi.group)
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1        54     81.159                     
2        48     70.579  6    10.58   0.1023
```

Here, the change in deviance is a score test and is distributed as a chi-squared statistic on (4-1) x (3-1) = 6 degrees of freedom.

The two approaches give similar answers *using my particular dataset*, but they may not always do so.  Both are statistically correct, but which one is most appropriate depends on your particular situation.  We don't have enough information to comment.

[This excellent post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59879/logistic-regression-anova-chi-square-test-vs-significance-of-coefficients-ano) provides more context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Limey, it is much clearer now! May I have the link of the post for more context? The current link directs to this post instead.